# Are there workarounds for using OpenMP reduction on floating point addition?

Tags: concurrency, openmp

I am currently working on parallelizing a nested for loop using C++ and OpenMP. Without going into the actual details of the program, I have constructed a basic example on the concepts I am using below:

```
float var = 0.f;
float distance = some float array;
float temp[] = some float array;
for(int i=0; i < distance.size; i++){
    \\some work
    for(int j=0; j < temp.size; j++){
        var += temp[i]/distance[j]
    }
}
```

I attempted to parallelize the above code in the following way:

```
float var = 0.f;
float distance = some float array;
float temp[] = some float array;
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared)
for(int i=0; i < distance.size; i++){
    \\some work
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:var)
    for(int j=0; j < temp.size; j++){
        var += temp[i]/distance[j]
    }
}
```

I then compared the serial program output with the parallel program output and I got incorrect result. I know that this is mainly due to the fact that floating point arithmetic is not associative. But are there any workarounds to this that give exact results?

Comment: I doubt your problem has anything to do with floating point arithmetic associativity. Here, you need to declare `reduction(+:var)` at your `i` loop level and remove the `#pragma omp` at the `j` loop level altogether. Just try that and let us know...

Comment: Also, why not compute once `float factor=1; for(int j=0; j<temp.size;j++) factor*=1/distance[j];` than replace the second loop by a mere `var += temp[i]*factor;` ?

Comment: @Gilles .. what I want is to parallelize also the inner loop.. if i remove the #pragma omp from the second loop I don't need the reduction(+:var) in the outermost loop because the inner loop will be done serially.

Comment: @Brice in the actual program I have different calculations, I just gave a quick example which describes what I want in a nutshell.

Comment: As to floating point math not being associative you can do the reduction manually and add the partial sums or consider Kahan summation.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ?

Comment: @Gilles by your suggestion, var is computed serially, so I do not need a reduction on it.

Comment: I think you have the wrong understanding of how OpenMP works. Keeping only the outer loop parallel is the most effective way to get it done (and BTW, since I doubt you had enabled nested parallelism, the inner loop wasn't parallelized anyway). Furthermore, irrespective of whether you also parallelize the inner loop or not, the `reduction(+:var)` has to go at the outer loop's level, otherwise, the code is wrong and will give bad results. Just try it and tell us how it goes.

Comment: @Gilles your comments are basically the answer to the question, with quite a deal of details. Would you mind to make an answer out of them?

Comment: @Brice sure, but I want first confirmation from the OP that it did indeed fix the issue, since he didn't post a MCV, I cannot test myself and be sure there isn't some hidden extra issue that need to be fixed too.

Comment: @Gilles it does work in this case. What I forgot to add in this example is that after the inner loop is computed, some work is done on the array 'distance' using the 'var' variable and then 'var' is set to 0. I have tried your suggestion on my code and it doesn't change the results. However, on this example you are right it does make a difference. Also, yes I had omp_set_nested(true) outside.

Comment: OK. So are you happy to keep it like this or do you want to go further. If so, you'll have to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for us to be able to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @Gilles I'm happy with this thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've posted a more elaborated answer which I hope will help you to understand the gist of your problem, and why my initial suggestion was enough to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the lack of associativity of floating point arithmetic might be an issue in some cases, the code you show here exposes a much more essential problem which you need to address first: the status of the `var` variable in the outer loop.

Indeed, since `var` is modified inside the `i` loop, even if only in the `j` part of the `i` loop, it needs to be "privatized" somehow. Now the exact status it needs to get depends on the value you expect it to store upon exit of the enclosing `parallel` region:

- If you don't care about its value at all, just declare it `private` (or better, declare it inside the `parallel` region.
- If you need its final value at the end of the `i` loop, and considering it accumulates a sum of values, most likely you'll need to declare it `reduction(+:)`, although `lastprivate` might also be what you want (impossible to say without further details)
- If `private` or `lastprivate` was all you needed, but you also need its initial value upon entrance of the `parallel` region, then you'll have to consider adding `firstprivate` too (no need of that if you went for `reduction` as it is already been taken care of)

That should be enough for fixing your issue.

Now, in your snippet, you also parallelized the inner loop. That is usually a bad idea to go for nested parallelism. So unless you have a very compelling reason for doing so, you will likely get much better performance by only parallelizing the outer loop, and leaving the inner loop alone. That won't mean the inner loop won't benefit from the parallelization, but rather that several instances of the inner loop will be computed in parallel (each one being sequential admittedly, but the whole process is parallel).
A nice side effect of removing the inner loop's parallelization (in addition to making the code faster) is that now all accumulations inside the privates `var` variables are done in the same order as when not in parallel. Therefore, your (hypothetical) floating point arithmetic issues inside the outer loop will now have disappeared, and only if you needed the final reduction upon exit of the `parallel` region might you still face them there.